# Валидация и форматирование кода

Tags: php, html, ide, dreamweaver

Когда я пишу код, то не слежу за правильной растановкой тегов и всего прочего. И получаются куски кода. Есть ли программа, позволяющая раставить код в правильном порядке или функция в Dreamweaver?

Comment: Опишите подробнее проблему. О чем вы вообще? Приведите примеры

Comment: Код беспорядочен можно ли его собрать в правильном порядке

Comment: @Давид, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отлично отреагирует на многие языки в одном файле прога phpdesigner. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

[Validator for Dreamweaver CS5](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=2188524)

Answer (score 0):

Если используете PHP, то пишите в программе Phpstorm. Там есть нормальное форматирование.
Ну и не смешивайте языки в одном файле, не будет ада такого.